# How can I install and uninstall themes in Ubuntu 14.04 .?

Tags: 14.04, themes

Can anybody please tell me that how can I change my theme in Ubuntu 14.04.
I know how to install but I don't now how to un-install.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your Ubuntu theme by going into

**System Settings --> Appearance**

[image]

Your custom themes are present in the `~/.themes` directory  ( and  in `/usr/share/themes/` unless you have not installed it as root user ) with their own name.

Simply deleting the folder (name of the theme you want to delete) will remove the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the Unity tweak tool from the Software Center. It allows you to change themes as well as icons.

As for installing, themes can be installed/removed like any other software using the software center or apt-get from terminal. You can find some good themes at http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html

Comment: I don't use the High Contrast theme - can I remove it?